# Don't autoflag answers on [community-ads] questions

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, open-source-advertising, automatic-flags

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212733/215468) just showed up in the 10k queue with an automatic quality score flag.

> [image]

Of *course* it has a low quality score - the rules pretty much say that they *have* to be low quality.

Can we at least tone down Community's inspection of answers to questions tagged [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads)?

Comment: Eh, it's not like these posts pop up that often, and it's only on Meta. Does it really matter if there's an exception or not? FWIW, it kind of guarantees that new community ads will come to someone's attention (make sure they follow the rules).

Comment: Flag it as VLQ. Not salvageable.

Comment: Come on, just _look_ at that font! The characters aren't even properly aligned!